# Swift 4 errors encountered while discovering extensions - photo will not load on UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting the following error message when I choose a photo from the photo library to populate a UIImageView in XCode 9.2:

- [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

The simulator is able to access the photo library and I am able to view the photos to make a selection, but when I click on the 'Choose' option to select a photo, the error is thrown and after the picker is dismissed the image is not populating the UIImageView.

I have searched Stack Overflow and am able to get rid of the error message if I do this step: From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > On your Environment Variables set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE in the value set disable.  However, this only gets rid of the error and does not fix the issue with my selected photo not populating the UIImageView.  I am new to Swift and Xcode and am stuck!  Please help!

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var avaImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fullnameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailLbl: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //get user details from user global var (from database)
    let username = (user!["username"] as? String)?.uppercased()
    let fullname = user!["fullname"] as? String
    let email = user!["email"] as? String
    let ava = user!["ava"] as? String

    //populate labels on view
    usernameLbl.text = username
    fullnameLbl.text = fullname
    emailLbl.text = email


}

@IBAction func edit_click(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    //select ava
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //selected image
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? 
           UIImage
        avaImg.image = image

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- The signature of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is wrong. In Swift 3+ it is

  ```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
                             didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
  ```
- The delegate method must be on the top level of the class (not in another method)

  ```
  @IBAction func edit_click(_ sender: Any) {

      //select ava
      let picker = UIImagePickerController()
      picker.delegate = self
      picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
      picker.allowsEditing = true
      self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

      //selected image
      let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
      avaImg.image = image
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

Comment: Fixed!  Thank you so much!!